# VRTK 3.3 Oculus controllers not tracking

Tags: oculus, vrtk

VRTK: 3.3
Unity3D: 2018.1.0f2
Oculus: SDK Oculus Utilities 1.27
SteamVR: 1.2.3

I started a project using Vive which is all up and running. Then I wanted to start working on getting Oculus up and running.  For some reason, the Oculus controllers are not tracking at all. They don't even show up.

To help track down the issue, I opened up the VRTK_SDKManager_Constructor scene as instructed, I then loaded up the StraightPointer scene.

Still no oculus controllers are visible nor are they tracking. Also, when I click on the joystick on the oculus controller, I get a laser projecting, but it's not coming from the controller. It's coming out from behind the headset.

I've tried this on two different computers, two different Oculus headsets.  Was hoping someone might have some insight into why the Oculus controllers are not working.

From my understanding, I am using the correct Oculus SDK.

Comment: You need to install the Oculus Avatar to "see" your hands. Also you need to *manually* add the prefabs to your VRTK Manager. The "Auto Populate" function doesn't work on Oculus for some reason. However, I am also having an issue where it doesn't track my controllers. I can see them, but that is about it.

Answer (score 1):

had a similar issue. here is what helped me:

- go to any working oculus example with hands (without vrtk)
- find LocalAvatar object
- export its children: DefaultHandMaterialManager and DefaultBodyMaterialManager as prefabs
- import them to your VRTK project
- insert their instances as children of LocalAvatar object (child of OculusVR object under SDKSetups)
- go to LocalAvatar's 'OVR Avatar' script
- set 'Default Hand Material Manager' and 'Default Body Material Manager' references to the objects you just created

hope this helps anyone